# How do I set a key property of array to object request i send to the database using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, post

i am trying to send a post request to DB with jquery. Though when i send the request which contains two properties; the first- a string(which is a date), and the second- an array, it sets the array key at the object to a string with square brackets at the end: `'daysweek[]'`.
the date key is fine as expected.
Does anybody know why is that happens and how can I fix it?

```
        let shifts = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
        $("#saveBtn").click((e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            let date = $('#date-input').val();
            if(!date){
                alert('Please insert a valid date');
                return
            }
            let daysweek = [];
            shifts.forEach(shift => {
                daysweek.push(shift.value);
            });
            $.post("/shifts?_method=PUT",
            {
                date: date,
                daysweek: daysweek
            },
            ()=>{
                $("#saveModal").modal("show");
            });
        });
```

And this is the req I get in the server:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  date: '2020-10-31',
  'daysweek[]': [
    'false', 'false', 'false',
    'false', 'false', 'false',
    'false', 'false', 'false',
    'false', 'false', 'false',
    'false', 'false', 'false',
    'false', 'false', 'false',
    'false', 'false', 'false'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try adding quotes in the object: `'daysweek': daysweek`. Using 3rd example from [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Hth.

Comment: yes, i have tried and it doesn't work as well.